# Theme table with html

Tags: theming

I am using custom module to insert and rendering data from Drupal Database.Is it possible rendering data using  theme table in my custom div block

Comment: Try to follow this I think this may help you : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could render content as table using **[Theme Table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7)**

```
<?php
$table_element = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' =>t('Your table is empty'),
);   
drupal_render($table_element);
?>
```

Here are some Examples for it:

- [Examples of theme_table() in Drupal 7](http://internetdevels.com/blog/examples-themetable-and-themefieldset-functions-drupal-7)
- [A Drupal theme table example](http://alvinalexander.com/drupal/drupal-theme-table-example-theme_table-function)
- [Drupal for Beginners: How to Create a Table Using theme_table()](http://zgadzaj.com/drupal-for-beginners-how-to-create-a-table-using-themetable)